Appsync - owner authorization with condition
I have type SomeEntity in schema with field isPrivate.
It is protected with @auth directive, which allows create operation for everyone and read only for owners:
@auth(
  rules: [
    { allow: groups, groups: ["user"], operations: [create] }
    { allow: owner, operations: [read] }
  ]
)

Now I'm thinking about how to allow read operation for owner if isPrivate == true and allowed for everyone if isPrivate == false.
Is it possible to use schema only or do I need a custom Lambda resolver?

You cannot directly use a field's value (isPrivate) to conditionally apply authorization rules within the schema alone. The @auth directive operates at the type and field level but does not support dynamic rules based on field values.
To achieve this

Use Custom Lambda Resolver.


This allows you to read the isPrivate field in the request, check
the user's ownership or group membership, and allow or deny access
accordingly.


Or Implement Field-Level Authorization in the schema. (If only some of the fields should protected)


Split SomeEntity into fields with separate rules, e.g., privateField for
owners and publicField for everyone.

Example :
type SomeEntity
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: groups, groups: ["user"], operations: [create] }
      { allow: owner, operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  ....
  .....
  privateField: String @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }])
  publicField: String
}


Thanks, I decided to go for custom Lambda resolver, however it requires to write data to Dynamodb directly
